# Nested loop on dates using purrr map

Tags: r, date, nested-loops, purrr

In a clinical trial, let's assume that I have :

(i) a dosing history file ('dosing'), with within-patient dose increase,

(ii) a lab parameter values file ('lab'), with assessment performed at dates that are not matching the dosing event dates.

I would like to add a column to the lab value file containing the dose received at the last dosing event. This is in preparation for an analysis of the lab values where the dose enters as a time-varying covariate. Below is a rather primitive code using `for` loops.

How could we obtain the same dataframe (or tibble) using functions from the `purrr` package?
Thanks a lot!

```
library(tidyverse)

#' Dosing file
#' ----------------------------------
dosdatID1<-c("2020-06-06", "2020-06-15", "2020-06-22", "2020-07-07", "2020-07-17")
dosdatID2<-c("2020-06-05", "2020-06-08", "2020-06-24", "2020-06-27")
dosing<-data.frame(
  ID=c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 4)),
  dosrec=c(1:5, 1:4),
  doslev=c(c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.9), c(0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3)), 
  dosdat=as.Date(c(dosdatID1, dosdatID2)))

#' Lab values file
#' ----------------------------------
labdatID1<-c("2020-06-17", "2020-06-24", "2020-07-08")
labdatID2<-c("2020-06-06", "2020-06-26")
labs<-data.frame(
  ID=c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 2)),
  labrec=c(1:3, 1:2),
  labval=round(c(rnorm(3, 10, 5), rnorm(2, 15, 5)), 2),
  labdat=as.Date(c(labdatID1, labdatID2))
)

labs$dos_current <- NA

# unique subject ID
u_subj<-unique(labs$ID)

# number of subjects
n_subj<-length(u_subj)

for(s in 1:n_subj){
  # subset the labs dataset for one particular subject s
  labs_1<-labs[which(labs$ID == u_subj[s]),]
  # unique lab records for subject s
  u_labrec <- unique(labs_1$labrec)
  # number of unique lab records for this particular subject s
  n_labrec <- length(u_labrec)
  
  for(lb in 1:n_labrec){
    # extract the date of this labrec
    dt_labrec <- labs_1$labdat[which(labs_1$labrec == u_labrec[lb])]
    ### get the current dose from the dosing dataset
    # subset the dosing dataset for one particular subject s
    dosing_1 <- dosing[which(dosing$ID == u_subj[s]),]
    # order the dates in decreasing order
    dosing_1 <- dosing_1[ order(dosing_1$dosdat, decreasing = TRUE), ]
    # get the latest dosing date which is less than or equal to the date of the labrec
    doslev <- dosing_1$doslev[grep("TRUE", dosing_1$dosdat <= dt_labrec)[1]]
    # input the current dose level into the labs dataset
    labs$dos_current[which(labs$ID == u_subj[s] & labs$labrec == u_labrec[lb])] <- doslev
  }
}

labs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a `tidyverse` solution, I would suggest you this one:

```
full_dosing <- dosing %>%
 mutate(labdat = dosdat) %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 complete(labdat = seq(min(labdat), max(labdat), "day"), ID) %>% 
 fill(dosdat, dosrec, doslev) %>% 
 ungroup()
 
left_join(labs, full_dosing, by = c("ID", "labdat"))
```

```
  ID labrec labval     labdat dosrec doslev     dosdat
1  1      1   4.92 2020-06-17      2    0.1 2020-06-15
2  1      2   2.89 2020-06-24      3    0.1 2020-06-22
3  1      3  14.01 2020-07-08      4    0.9 2020-07-07
4  2      1   3.92 2020-06-06      1    0.2 2020-06-05
5  2      2  17.58 2020-06-26      3    0.3 2020-06-24
```

However, it is less efficient than the `data.table` solution because you need to `complete` the `dosing` dataframe first.

---

The solution is based on this data:

```
#' Dosing file
#' ----------------------------------
dosdatID1<-c("2020-06-06", "2020-06-15", "2020-06-22", "2020-07-07", "2020-07-17")
dosdatID2<-c("2020-06-05", "2020-06-08", "2020-06-24", "2020-06-27")
dosing<-data.frame(
 ID=c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 4)),
 dosrec=c(1:5, 1:4),
 doslev=c(c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.9), c(0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3)), 
 dosdat=as.Date(c(dosdatID1, dosdatID2)))

#' Lab values file
#' ----------------------------------
labdatID1<-c("2020-06-17", "2020-06-24", "2020-07-08")
labdatID2<-c("2020-06-06", "2020-06-26")
labs<-data.frame(
 ID=c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 2)),
 labrec=c(1:3, 1:2),
 labval=round(c(rnorm(3, 10, 5), rnorm(2, 15, 5)), 2),
 labdat=as.Date(c(labdatID1, labdatID2))
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, no `purrr`-solotion from me. But using a rolling join on `data.table` will do the trick pretty fast.

functionality:
For each row in `labs`. it will find the last dosdat in `dosing` with the same `ID` before labdat, and add the values `dosdat` and `doslev` to the `labs`-data.table.

```
library( data.table )
#make them data.tables
setDT(dosing);setDT(labs)
#now rolling join by reference
labs[, c("dosdat", "doslev") := dosing[labs, .(dosdat = x.dosdat, doslev), 
                                       on = .(ID, dosdat = labdat), 
                                       roll = TRUE]][]
#    ID labrec labval     labdat     dosdat doslev
# 1:  1      1   2.67 2020-06-17 2020-06-15    0.1
# 2:  1      2  16.62 2020-06-24 2020-06-22    0.1
# 3:  1      3  11.64 2020-07-08 2020-07-07    0.9
# 4:  2      1   8.85 2020-06-06 2020-06-05    0.2
# 5:  2      2  10.91 2020-06-26 2020-06-24    0.3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very efficient indeed! As I didn't know about it, I looked at this blog which walks us through a 'rolling join' example ... : https://r-norberg.blogspot.com/2016/06/understanding-datatable-rolling-joins.html

Comment: If you think this is the right solution, you should accept it, so that it could be more useful for other users.